# Yarn in EMR is not spinning up more than 32 containers

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, bigdata, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I have a scenario where all the containers (around 50) should be up and running all the time for realtime spark queries.

Even though I set **spark.dynamicallocation.minExecutors =50**. it is not spinning up 50 executors. It is only spinning up 30 containers and remaining cores and memory is Unused.

Please let me know is there any limitations or way to resolve.

Comment: which type of node are you using?

Comment: what is the executor memory, executor cores u r giving? and driver cores and driver memory? does the available cores and memory fit in additional executors?